# Bootstrap columns vertical reordering

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

1) can i reorder columns vertically using bootstrap Pull and Push.
2) is there any class in bootstrap to apply border to div or do we need to write our own class.

Suppose i have a DOM structure as below:

A

B

C

But i want to display it on mobile in below sequence

B

C

A

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-xs-12">A</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">B</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">C</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: have you looked at the documentation? try playing around with http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering
What have you tried?

Comment: Push pull doesn't work vertically (for full width columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-push-12">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-pull-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="alert alert-info">A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="alert alert-info">C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will do the trick

Comment: is that possible with keeping all the div to col-xs-12

Comment: you can try it now

Comment: If you have problem for the vertical col pushes you can try with js like this :

Comment: $( "div:first" ).append().insertBefore( "div:last" );